# Is there a way to automatically update images in overleaf?

Tags: images, overleaf

I work on a research project where we produce many graphs/images in Matlab, that are updated regularly.

In order to update our draft in overleaf, we constantly have to re-upload updated graphs manually. Is there a more efficient or automated way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a subscription for premium features, the recommended method would be to use the git-bridge integration. This allows you to push changes to image files (or others) from your local device to your Overleaf project. Some prefer this workflow to the manual upload approach. Please see: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub

Another option is, again with a subscription, is to use Dropbox synchronization to automatically update files from your local machine to your Overleaf project. See here for more info:https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Dropbox_Synchronization.